# Article before a proper noun?

Tags: articles, proper-nouns

I can't tell exactly when an article "the" should go before a proper noun. For example both sound right to me in the following examples:

> These stuffs are imported from United States.
>   These stuffs are imported from **the** United States.
>   History of Britain can date back to Medieval.
>   History of Britain can date back to **the** Medieval.
>   A question is asked on ELL.SE.
>   A question is asked on **the** ELL.SE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **PROPER NOUNS**
>
> - Use the with names of geographical areas, rivers, mountain ranges, groups of islands, canals, and oceans.   Example: Hiking across the
>     Rocky Mountains would be difficult.
> - Use the with countries that have plural names   Example: I have never been to the Netherlands.
> - Use the with Organizations, government, committees, parties, associations, foundations, clubs   Example: the Congress of the United
>     States, the United Nations (the UN).
> - Use the with countries that include the words "republic", "kingdom", or "states" in their names.  Example: She is visiting the
>     United States.
> - Use the with newspaper names.   Example: She works for the New York Times.
> - Use the with the names of famous buildings, works of art, museums, or monuments.   Example: We went to the Louvre and saw the Mona Lisa.
> - Use the with the names of hotels & restaurants, unless these are named after a person.   Example: They are staying at the Hilton on 6th
>     street.
> - Use the with the names of families, but not with the names of individuals.  Example: We're having dinner with the Smiths tonight.
>
> **WHEN NOT TO USE "THE"**
>
> - Do not use the with names of countries (except for the special cases above).   Example: He's just returned from Zimbabwe.
> - Do not use the with names of shops   Example: I'll get the card at Smith's.
> - Do not use the with uncountable nouns   Example: Milk is often added to tea in England.
> - Do not use the with the names of individual mountains, lakes and islands   Example: Mount McKinley is the highest mountain in Alaska.
> - Do not use the with most names of towns, streets, stations and airports   Example: She lives in Florence.

For your sentences:
These stuffs are imported from the United States. (countries with states in their names)
History of Britain can date back to The Medieval.
But we write: History of Britain can date back to Medieval Times.
A question is asked on ELL.SE.

Comment: Your answer is helpful and mostly coveys very good rules of thumb. Unofrtunately, the EF website you linked to isn't and doesn't. It would be best if you removed that link! :-) +1

Comment: [To illustrate, it says **Don't use *the* with uncountable nouns**. But we use *the* with uncountable nouns all the time: *Can you pass me the water* or *The air in Mexico city ...*, for example.] Thanks for removing that link!!

Comment: We don't need to capitalize the "the" in "the Medieval", do we?