# Article usage in "the crunch of tires in dirt", "a cloud of dust"

Tags: articles

Can you explain the author’s use of "the" and "a" in the following sentence:

> I heard **the** crunch of tires in dirt, and **a** cloud of dust wafted over me.

So, ignoring the two pronouns, “I” and “me”, there are five nouns in that sentence: *crunch, tires, dirt, cloud,* and *dust.* However only two of them — *crunch* and *cloud* have articles, and even there the articles are different: ”crunch” gets the definite article, *the;* but the indefinite article, *a,* is used for “dust”. What rules are used to decide when to precede a noun with an article at all, and then which of “the” or “a” to use when an article is deemed to be appropriate.

For example, compare the original sentence with:

> I heard **a** crunch of tires in dirt, and **a** cloud of dust wafted over me.

Is that second version wrong? It sounds OK to my ears, but even if it has no grammatical issues, how is it different in meaning? And then, how about this third option:

> I heard **the** crunch of tires in dirt, and **the** cloud of dust wafted over me.

That now does sound strange. The use of the definite article for “cloud” doesn’t sound right, but what, if anything, is wrong with it?

Or why not even have:

> I heard **a** crunch of **the** tires in **the** dirt, and **a** cloud of **the** dust wafted over me.

Comment: Please show how you have tried to understand why those words were used in the sentence, and why you are confused by them.

Answer (score 1):

Look - an [article about articles](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/articles/)!  Go figure ;)

That article explains it well but I will summarize some of it here.

### Definite vs Indefinite

**Definite Article:** using "the" means that you are talking about a specific instance of the noun.  It wasn't just any crunch of tires in the dirt, it was *the* unmistakable crunch of tires in the dirt.

**Indefinite Article:** using "a"/"an" means that you are *not* talking about a specific instance.  You are invoking the general idea of a dust cloud rather than a specific dust cloud previously mentioned.

To illustrate further with a separate example:

- **Indefinite** - "My grandma's house was destroyed by **a** tornado last year."  We don't care to specify which tornado, or maybe we don't know.  It could be that the more important topic was the destruction of Grandma's house.
- **Definite** - "My grandma's house was destroyed by **the** tornado that hit Kansas last year."  We do want to specify which tornado, perhaps because the larger topic of conversation was that specific tornado.

### Omission of Articles

This is sometimes called a “[zero article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English#Zero_article).”  It usually implies that the noun is being discussed as a generic or abstract idea.

I don't think there is a hard-and-fast rule for this, but the more you speak with English speakers the easier it is to know what sounds natural.

More examples:

- Absolute power corrupts absolutely.
- Almond Joy's got nuts, Mounds don't. --> [More info about articles with proper nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126097/article-before-a-proper-noun)
- Patience is a virtue.
- Space, the final frontier.

Answer (score 0):

> I heard a crunch of the tires in the dirt, and a cloud of the dust wafted over me.

this seems like one of those unexplainable things. the reason why the bottom line doesn't work is that its broken up way too much and sounds kind of robotic. like its just not good or right English. it uses words that are completely unneeded and redundantly uses *the.*

> I heard the crunch of tires in dirt, and a cloud of dust wafted over me.

the reason this one works is that we usually use *the* first when describing things like this. its more of just how people talk. you can use *a* but it sounds strange to use it because people just don't use it.

I think the indefinite article *a* is used on dust due to the fact that logically we would understand that off-road cars or cars on dirt tend to make clouds of dust. it's in a lot of media. and due to that, say *the* for the cloud of dust just sounds like you are over-explaining, undermining the reader's competence, and being redundant by using *the* a little too much.

> I heard a crunch of tires in dirt, and a cloud of dust wafted over me.

this one isn't really that wrong, it just shows that the point of view doesn't have the time to realize, or doesn't know where the tires are.