# When do you use determiner "The" before a proper noun?

Tags: determiners, proper-nouns

I've been translating some stories from my mother tongue (Spanish) to English, but I have struggled with certain titles, for example:

- **La Siguanaba** in English would be **the Siguanaba**. **This is a unique spirit.**
- **El Cadejo** in English would be **the Cadejo**. This can be considered as **a species** because there are two of them, but only two.

My concern is the following, **Cadejo** and **Siguanaba** are *proper names* from mythical beasts/spirits. However, I'm not sure if I should treat them as regular [proper names](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126097/article-before-a-proper-noun) in the stories (Siguanaba or Cadejo without the), or "the" determiner should precede the name as in Spanish.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal to use articles before the names of those legendary creatures.

> “The Siguanaba” is a Salvadoran mythological character that shows
>   herself in a phantom female form and beautiful body.
>
> In Guatemala, the Siguanaba appears as a beautiful, seductive woman
>   with very long hair.

[image]

> The cadejo is a character from Salvadoran, Belizean, Nicaraguan, Costa
>   Rican, Honduran, Guatemalan and southern Mexican folklore.
>
> The cadejo is a character from Central American and southern Mexican
>   folklore. There is a good white cadejo and an evil black cadejo.
>
> The Cadejo has been described in several ways. It's usually a big,
>   doglike creature with hooves of a deer and abundant fur.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, I wasn't sure!

Comment: By the way, where did you find this article?

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete - I quoted from more than one article or book. I found them by using Google's 'exact text' search. To do this, enclose the text you want to find in double quote marks, for example like this: `"the Siguanaba"` or `"the Cadejo"`.

Answer (score -2):

> **No article** is used before names.

In your examples **Siguanaba** and **Cadejo** are *proper names* of mythical beasts and spirits. **"Siguanaba"** is a unique spirit and **"Cadejo"** is a specific species.

> **The** is used to mean there is **only one**
>   spirit or species : **"La Siguanaba" (i.e., the Siguanaba)**; **"El Cadejo" (i.e., the Cadejo)**.